# Tamanho do vetor em um JSON no Shell Script

Tags: json, script, shell-script

Gostaria de pegar o tamanho de um vetor em um JSON no shell scriipt mas só estou conseguindo pegar o tamanho de cada  string  do vetor, ou seja, para o exemplo :

```
#!/bin/bash

j='{"Nomes": { "nome": ["maria", "jose", "vitor","caio"] }}'

echo $j
echo  $j | jq -r ".Nomes | .nome[] | length"
```

Sai além do JSON:

```
5
4
5
4
```

Mas eu queria que saisse 4 que é a quantidade de ítens no vetor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente remover os `[]`:

```
echo  $j | jq -r ".Nomes.nome | length"
```